# windows 10 mobile camera

Tags: c#, exception, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I'm trying to use the camera in a Windows 10 Mobile App but an error is occurring when I take the picture and try to show it on the screen.

Here's the code:

```
CameraCaptureUI captureUI = new CameraCaptureUI();
captureUI.PhotoSettings.Format = CameraCaptureUIPhotoFormat.Jpeg;
captureUI.PhotoSettings.CroppedSizeInPixels = new Size(200, 200);

StorageFile photo = await captureUI.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);

if (photo == null)
{
    // User cancelled photo capture
    return;
}

StorageFolder destinationFolder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("ProfilePhotoFolder", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

await photo.CopyAsync(destinationFolder, "ProfilePhoto.jpg", NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
await photo.DeleteAsync();

IRandomAccessStream stream = await photo.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmap = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync();

SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmapBGR8 = SoftwareBitmap.Convert(softwareBitmap,
BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied);

SoftwareBitmapSource bitmapSource = new SoftwareBitmapSource();
await bitmapSource.SetBitmapAsync(softwareBitmapBGR8);

imageControl.Source = bitmapSource;
```

The exception message:

> An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The system cannot find the file specified.
> (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued."

Someone can help me with this?

Comment: Have you resolved it?

Comment: Yes, it did. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you deleted the `photo` but then trying to read the `photo` which has just deleted, so the exception "FileNotFound" will throw. Please remove the following code line it will work.

```
 await photo.DeleteAsync();
```

But I think what you really want to do is to delete the photo which is got from the `CameraCaptureUI`, and then read the photo from the local folder which has already copied. In that case, code should be as followings:

```
await photo.CopyAsync(destinationFolder, "ProfilePhoto.jpg", NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
await photo.DeleteAsync();
StorageFile newphoto = await destinationFolder.GetFileAsync("ProfilePhoto.jpg");
IRandomAccessStream stream = await newphoto.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
```